# feed multiple lines to bash variable from text file

Tags: bash

This is probably going to be marked as duplicate, but after reading several posts, I still can't make my bash script work.
I have a text file with multiple lines; each line has 1 string only. I want to import the content to a bash variable, such as each line is a separate element.
So, as an example, if `MYVAR` is the mentioned variable, I want to  be able to access any element by its position, e.g.:

```
for i in $(seq 0 2)
do
        echo ${MYVAR[$i]}
done
```

The above is just an example; I do not need a for loop, that is why i have not used `while read LINE` strategy.
I have tried several ways, but the file keeps being imported as 1 long string which includes the whole content. Hope my purpose is clear, I appreciate any help.

Comment: Why have you not used a `while read` loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the IFS to newline only, and read the file into array with ():

```
OFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
MYVAR=($(<myfilename.txt))
for i in $(seq 0 2)
do
        echo ${MYVAR[$i]}
done
# setup the IFS to its original value
IFS=$OFS
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked!
This morning, with a fresher mind, I reviewed my script. What puzzled me is that IFS by default should be space, newline and tab. Thus, the script above should work (and it does) even without changing IFS. I realized that one of my initial mistakes was  to put a space after the '=' in 'MYVAR=($(<myfilename.txt))'
That causes an error (weird?): syntax error near unexpected token `(' so I removed the outer parentheses, which put me on the wrong track. I just thought I would give you some feedback on your script. Thank you for solving my problem!